# How to edit tooltip opacity in vscode? (how to change the intellisense suggestions transparency)

Tags: tooltip, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in vscode.
When I write code the tooltip annoys me, because I use divided screen in macOS
so I want to make the tooltips semi-transparent without press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>
like this image:

[image: Description]

Answer (score 8):

Try this `colorCustomization` in your settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorSuggestWidget.background": "#ff000060"
}
```

The last two digits, in this case `60` are opacity.  There a few more `editorSuggestWidget` options to change too.

Comment: Does this still work as of 2023? I have the exact code above, and "editorSuggestWidget" was suggested, but nothing has changed. It is also still grey, hasn't changed to be red/pink.

Comment: Aha, there is also `"editorHoverWidget.background"` which does work. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-widget-colors for all options.

Answer (score 3):

https://wannabedev.tistory.com/37

I found it, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's great - looks like my answer to your question was correct.  It would be encouraging if you accepted the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's a visual studio feature not yet available in visual studio code.

At present, the only option is to disable the pop-up altogether, in which case you don't get the hinting, which is not ideal.

There are a lot of threads on GitHub about the position and opacity of the tool tip (search terms like 'tooltip intellisense position' you'll find a bunch).  You can add your voice there.